# There are no "holes" in the Bruhat decomposition of parabolic cell $Pw_1P$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, bruhat-order, chevalley-groups

Let $G$ be a split reductive algebraic group (over a local field if you like), $B$ be a fixed Borel subgroup, and $P$ be a fixed standard parabolic subgroup. Let $W$ be the Weyl group of $G$. For $w\in W$, denote $C(w)=BwB$.

Given Weyl elements $w>w'>w_1$ (Bruhat order), if $C(w)\subset Pw_1P$, do we know that $C(w')\subset Pw_1P$? It's like to ask whether there are holes in $Pw_1P$. On the other hand, this amounts to asking if $Pw_1P\cap \Omega_{w_1}$ is closed in $\Omega_{w_1}$, where $$\Omega_{w_1}:=\coprod_{w\ge w_1}C(w).$$

Any comments and references are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the condition is that $BwB \subset P w_0 P$ if and only if $w = w_1 w_0 w_2$ for some $w_1, w_2 \in W_I$.  Here $W_I$ is the Weyl group of a standard Levi of $P$.  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118974/general-bruhat-decomposition-with-parabolic-not-necessarily-borel for a related question.  This should give the answer to your explicit question, with a bit of work with minimal-length representatives, I think.

Comment: @Marty's thought is correct; this is Corollaire 5.20 of [Borel and Tits](http://numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1965__27__55_0) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=207712)).

Comment: @LSpice thanks for the comments and the reference. I am more curious if that explicit question has already an answer in the literature.

Comment: The formulation of the question is too loose, since you apparently want the group to be *split* (over some field which isn't important here).  Also, it's helpful to give the Weyl group a label such as $W$; then "a Weyl element $w$" just means $w \in W$.  The standard use of the symbol $w_0$ is for the "longest element" of $W$ (relative to some fixed set of simple reflections).   Finally, it's enough to specify that $P$ is a standard parabolic $P_I$ for a subset $I$ of the simple reflections.

Comment: @JimHumphreys Professor Humphreys, thanks for your comment. I changed the formulation a little bit accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition $C(w)\subseteq Pw_1P$ implies $PwP=Pw_1P\Rightarrow\overline{PwP}=\overline{Pw_1P}$.

Moreover $w\ge w'\Rightarrow\overline{BwB}\supseteq\overline{Bw'B}\Rightarrow\overline{PwP}\supseteq \overline{Pw'P}$.

Similarly $w'\ge w_1\Rightarrow\overline{Bw'B}\supseteq\overline{Bw_1B}\Rightarrow\overline{Pw'P}\supseteq \overline{Pw_1P}$.

Together, one gets $\overline{Pw'P}=\overline{Pw_1p}$.

But then $Pw'P=Pw_1P$ and in particular $C(w')\subseteq Pw_1P$.

Remark: One can show stronger that the set of $w$ with $C(w)\subseteq Pw_1P$ is the double coset $W_Iw_1W_I$ and that this double coset forms a Bruhat interval, i.e., there are $w_{min},w_{max}\in D$ such that $w\in D\Leftrightarrow w_{min}\le w\le w_{max}$. After a very cursory search I found it without proof in the paper "Parabolic double cosets in Coxeter groups" by Billey et al. Proposition 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could your kindly explain further how $\overline{BwB}\supset \overline{Bw'B}$ implies $\overline{PwP}\supset \overline{Pw'P}$ in the second line? Thanks.

Comment: $PwP=P(BwB)P$ is dense in $P\overline{BwB}P$. Hence $\overline{PwP}=\overline{P\overline{BwB}P}\supseteq\overline{P\overline{Bw'B}P}=\overline{Pw'P}$.