# Errata for Casselman's unpublished notes

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

In the first chapter of W. Casselman's unpublished notes on representation theory, there is at least one stated result which is not true:

[image]

A counterexample to this last result is given in the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118974/general-bruhat-decomposition-with-parabolic-not-necessarily-borel).  Besides Casselman's notes, I have never seen any claim of such an isomorphism for an arbitrary double coset $P_{\Theta}wP_{\Omega}$ for parabolic subgroups.  Of course such an isomorphism is known when $\Theta = \Omega=  \emptyset$.

There is also the result here which I have never seen anywhere else, relating length to elementary conjugation:

[image]

The proof does not seem to come as easily as it is claimed, and I am starting to think it is not true.

The later chapters rely on some of these very carefully stated results.  I want to convince myself that the important results in Casselman's notes are properly justified.  Is there a known list of errata for Casselman's notes?  Or another reference which carefully goes through the same things?

Comment: It may be worth to quote from the [notes](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf): _This draft of Casselman’s notes was worked over by the Séminaire Paul Sally in 1992–93. ... Casselman has neither approved nor disavowed the end product._  Casselman refers to the notes as _"now out of date and full of minor errors"_ ... _"the most egregious is the formulation of the Bruhat-Tits KTK reduction."_ which may well refer to the cited [MO posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118974/general-bruhat-decomposition-with-parabolic-not-necessarily-borel)